# Upload file with php form

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

I have a code for my php form that i like. I tried to integrate, with several tutorial on web,  some code to upload file. But no success!
Need help! here is the code i use... Tks

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "my@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Message from website";
    function died($error)
    {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists

    if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
        $error_message.= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
        $error_message.= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message.= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array(
            "content-type",
            "bcc:",
            "to:",
            "cc:",
            "href"
        );
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message.= "First Name: " . clean_string($first_name) . "\n";
    $email_message.= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message.= "Telephone: " . clean_string($telephone) . "\n";
    $email_message.= "Comments: " . clean_string($comments) . "\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>



    <!-- include your own success html here -->





    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: where is the upload code, I dont see it

Comment: Also, the form code is pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

You've to change your html from something like:

```
FROM: <form action="file.php" method="post">
TO: <form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to see how upload a file.
After the upload you can attach the file at the e-mail.

Take a look at: [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail) to see how to attach file using mail()

Comment: That is realy helpfull thank you. It is uploading my files in my upload folder, but there is no attachment in the email. I don't see any tips in "w3s" for that. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added a link in the answer... Take a look.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about uploading a file, but your code only refers to delivering a message using PHP. Here is some basic PHP code for uploading a file:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Here is a basic tutorial around uploading a file using PHP that you might find helpful: [Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)